# Add values on One2many field onchange

Tags: odoo, onchange, odoo-13, one2many

I'm trying to add values in my one2many field onchange.
I tried using the `[(0,0, {values})]` but nothing happened. Any idea on how to implement it?

```
custom_line_ids = fields.One2many('mrp.production', 'product_id', 'Custom Line')   
@api.onchange('product_id')
    def add_custom_line_ids(self):
        mrp = self.env['mrp.productions'].search([])
        result = []
        
        vals = {
                'sequence': self.sequence,
                'name': self.name,
                'product_id': self.product_id,
                'date_planned_start': self.date_planned_start,
                'state': self.state,
            }
        self.update({'custom_line_ids':[(0, 0, vals)]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using `update` method, which only update the model's value but not yet stored on database. You should use `write` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value in `onchange`. This would work:

```
custom_line_ids = fields.One2many('mrp.production', 'product_id', 'Custom Line')   

@api.onchange('product_id')
def add_custom_line_ids(self):
    vals = {}
    mrp_ids = self.env['mrp.productions'].search([])
    if mrp_ids:
        for mrp in mrp_ids:
            vals['custom_line_ids']=[(0,0,{
                'date': mrp.date,  
               
            })]
    return {'value': vals}
```